# Using jQuery in navigation when link is clicked - go to target page, then scroll to a specific section of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so I have been looking round on here and have seen some similar questions posted, but can't understand the answers in relation to the problem that I have. So apologies if this is duplicating a question someone else has posted.

The problem I have;

I have a multi-page site that I am building on the Concrete5 platform. I have a few sections - home, products, about & contact.

In the about page there are then 3 sections (who we are, product development & our story) - all of which are styled to be 100vh and fill the screen, these are then scrolled through using a jQuery scroll function that allows for the mouse wheel to be used to scroll up and down(the page scrolls the full 100vh section at a time) - so it has the same effect as this - http://www.bang-olufsen.com/en - it also contains similar 'dots' that can be clicked to scroll up or down. I have used IDs to get this.

What I need is that on the about tab, in the navigation - it has a sub-menu that contains the three section links (currently these all go to the top of the about page).

I have tried this www.example.com/about#our-story etc - this doesnt work as Concrete5 seems to read this as a new page and just shows a blank page that has no content.

So what I need is for the sub-menu link to take the user to about page and then once this is loaded - go and find the relevant section i.e if the user clicked on the 'our-story' link it would go to the about page and then scroll down to the our story section.

Any ideas?

To anyone who can provide the solution, I won't know who you are. If you are looking for payment, I can tell you I don't have money. But what I do have are a very particular set of skills, skills I have acquired over a very short career. Skills that make me very poor as a jQuery developer. If you help me now, that'll be the end of it. But if you don't, I will struggle for the next few hours - maybe days, if you help me I won't, and I will owe you :P

Thanks

Comment: if you are looking for something like : http://www.almasresidential.ir/Almas.aspx?almas=1
  Then i can help you

Comment: _"I have tried this www.example.com/about#our-story etc"_. Did you try "www.example.com/about.html#our-story"

Comment: are you using any script to make User Friendly URL?

Comment: Munawir - yeah tried that. Ram singh - it is just done through the platform, so I don't want to have to play with that if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery Animtion like this :

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.MySecondSection').offset().top - 90 }, 2000, function () {
            });
        });

    </script>
```

**Edit** :

```
<script>
                $("#myClickableItem").click(function () {
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.MySecondSection').offset().top - 90 }, 2000, function () {
                    });
                });
    </script>
```

-90 is for the height of the Navbar. you can skip or change it.

**Edit:**

```js
  $("#myClickableItem").click(function() {
    $("body").animate({
      scrollTop: $('#div2').offset().top
    }, 2000, function() {});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="width:100%;height:500px;float:right;background-color:#ffeeee">
  <span id="myClickableItem" style="cursor:pointer;">Click Me!</span>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="width:100%;height:500px;float:right;background-color:#eeffee">2</div>
```

Chech the snippet please.

Comment: Hi Salman, thanks for the response. How does this know when to trigger though? ie how would it know to go to the 2nd section if the click has come before the page has loaded? Thanks

Comment: ok so I have this?   `$("li.item_172 a").click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#our-story').offset().top - 90 }, 2000, function () {
        });
    });`  it doesn't work - ideas?

Comment: Have you added jquery library to your page?
Try putting an alert('ok'); in the function and check if it has been triggered.

Comment: Hi Salman, yeah added - <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> - just tried the alert and that pops up fine on the click - then it loads the 'about' page - but then nothing scrolls? Thanks

Comment: please choose this as the answer so it may helps other

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply need an html link anchor?

Create a link`<a href="#anyword">Jump to any place</a>`

Then you need a target at the place in the page you want to jump to:

```
<a name="anyword">Jump to this place</a>
```

Comment: Hi Dawcars, thanks for the response, I don't understand what you mean? I mentioned that this didnt work in the link when clicked - so the link on the sub-menu has to be simply ....com/about and then once it gets to the page it needs to trigger the appropriate call to go to the section. So how would it do that? Thanks

Comment: Your link needs to be something like: `<a href="www.website.com/about#about">Jump to any place</a>` and the anchor on your about page needs to be something like: `<a name="about">About</a>`

Comment: Hi Dawcars, the thing is, this is just one page - so the about page is the sub page - and as I mentioned about Concrete5 renders the www.website.com/about#about" as a completely different page to www.website.com/about - so when I put that link in, it just breaks it? Thanks

Comment: You probably just need `<a href="#about">Jump to any place</a>` in the href rather than the full path, so it stays in the same page but jumps to the anchor.

Comment: Hi Dawcars - no, the problem is that its when the user isn't on the about page - its when they are on for example, the homepage. Hence I think this is a JS thing - because it needs to go to the about page first and then do something. I think what you are suggesting would work if the user was already on the about page. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104414/discussion-between-dawcars-and-christopher-john).

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the page extension like `www.example.com/about.html#our-story`

Comment: Hi Munawir, tried this and it just breaks stuff - C5 doesn't seem to like any links with # in them. Thanks